# Authentication Scheme is not being picked up in .net 6

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

//startup.cs class
I have set authentication scheme

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

         services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; });
        }
```

//UseAuthentication is also set

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
        }
```

//Error I am facing

```
System.InvalidOperationException: **No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found**. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What Am I Missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Add these code in `lunchSetting.json`

```
 "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": true,
        "anonymousAuthentication": false,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52171/",
            "sslPort": 44308
        }
    }
```

Comment: startup.cs has been removed in .Net 6,you need to check your version.